# python django - Images are blank when written using decoded base64

Tags: javascript, python, django, base64

My django website aims at allowing users to combine different clothing picture on one single canvas.

However, the saved image is blank.

I have applied one fiddle, please see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/elmouse19/1e82vovw/).

I've used the methods recommended by some forums.

Here is the views.py

```py
@csrf_protect
@csrf_exempt 
def savewearingimg(request):

    imgEncodeString = request.POST.get('imgBase64')
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():

        singleItemNames = request.POST.getlist('singleItemNames[]') 
        saveWearingName = request.POST.get('saveWearingName') #string
        positionsX = request.POST.getlist('positionsX[]')
        positionsY = request.POST.getlist('positionsY[]')
        userWidths = request.POST.getlist('sizes[]') 

        imgEncodeString = request.POST.get('imgBase64').partition(",")[2]#for header removing
        img64Data = base64.b64decode(imgEncodeString) #other decoding fundctions failed
        BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        preFileStr = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media\\photos\\wearing\\")
        poFileStr=str(request.user)+'_itemName_'+saveWearingName+'.jpg'
        filename = preFileStr +poFileStr

        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(img64Data)

    return render(request,'combinewearing.html')
```

And here is part of the javascript combinewearing.js

```
$(function() {
   canvas = document.getElementById('save-canvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
});

 $('#saveWearingBtn').click(function(){

        drawToSave(alreadyPutImg,originalWidths);
     });
 function drawToSave(alreadyPutImg,originalWidths){

        loadImagesMike(sources, function(images_) { //the original author is Mike
            for(var i=0; i<ImgPutArr.length; i++ ){
                var img_iter = ImgPutArr[i];
         context.drawImage(images_[i],img_iter.x,img_iter.y,img_iter.w,img_iter.h);
                console.log('images_[i]: '+images_[i] );//[object HTMLImageElement]
                i++;
            }

        });


        var myDataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); 
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/savewearingimg/",
          data: {
             'csrfmiddlewaretoken': "{{ csrf_token }}",
             'imgBase64': myDataURL,
             'singleItemNames': alreadyPutName,//array storing what users have added to the canvas
             'saveWearingName':$('#saveWearingName').val(), //end-users can customized his/her desired wearing title
             'positionsX':positionsX, //position array storing every clothing pictures
             'positionsY':positionsY,
             'sizes':sizes,
          },

        }).done(function(o) {
            alert('saved');
          console.log('saved');

        });/*end ajax*/
     } 
/*sources is an array storing all the user-selected pictures absolute path*/
function loadImagesMike(sources, callback) {
    var images = [];
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    // get num of sources
    for(var src in sources) {
      numImages++;
    }
    for(var src in sources) {
      images[src] = new Image();
      images[src].onload = function() {
        if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
          callback(images);
        }
      };
      images[src].src = sources[src];
    }
  }
```

There is no error message. Only the image is blank.

However, if I follow the same steps and same string as [this link](https://blog.csdn.net/QZC295919009/article/details/42712801)suggests, the image would not be blank.

So I suppose that the problem is due to the string's content. My failed 
 string content links to [this google doc link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IjDifuTgIX_t0ON25HAOrwnDBMMhNu_rNM4QtHqcay8/edit)(Correct me if I'm wrong, thank you.)

---

I've just found that this rectangle will show up in the image....
So what should I adjust?

```
context.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
context.stroke();
```

Comment: Hi there! sounds like a fun project! It's odd indeed and should work, codewise speaking. The thing that did come up to me since you added a google doc link with the BASE64 code is that the BASE64 code isn't complete or invalid for some reason. If you'll look at the base64 of the link you shared, and copy paste it to this website https://onlinepngtools.com/convert-base64-to-png you'll receive a PNG format image. But if i use your BASE64 string nothing shows up. Can you maybe share your image you have encoded? I'll try to check if maybe the base64 encoding is going wrong or something like that.

Comment: Thank you. I have randomly chosen different images from the Internet, but nothing helps. Originally I choose the image under the folder in my laptop.

Comment: So does this solve the issue or are you still having trouble ? :)

Comment: Hi, forgot to tell you that the tool you listed above returns a blank image if I paste the string in the google docs I mentioned ~~

Comment: @Cindy Hi , can you help to fix it please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69358408/base64-saves-blank-image-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by moving THIS PART to the interior of the **loadImagesMike()** function (inside **drawToSave()**)

THIS PART---->

```
        var myDataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); 
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/savewearingimg/",
      data: {
         'csrfmiddlewaretoken': "{{ csrf_token }}",
         'imgBase64': myDataURL,
         'singleItemNames': alreadyPutName,//array storing what users have added to the canvas
         'saveWearingName':$('#saveWearingName').val(), //end-users can customized his/her desired wearing title
         'positionsX':positionsX, //position array storing every clothing pictures
         'positionsY':positionsY,
         'sizes':sizes,
      },

    }).done(function(o) {
        alert('saved');
      console.log('saved');

    });/*end ajax*/
```

THIS PART is moved after the for loop, and it is inside the **loadImagesMike()** function.